# Beamer french + beamer + tikz label + +b environment = booom

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, babel-french

I can’t use the label syntax `label={45:my text}` to put a label at 45 degrees when beamer + babel french are enabled. I tried various stuff like `[fragile]`, `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` or `\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\shorthandoff{;}\shorthandoff{:}}`, none of them work:

I have [image]
instead of [image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % Important, or I get issues on other code when using french babel like "! Package tikz

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytest}{+b}{
  % scantokens makes it *nearly* work, but then it fails again when using \only
  \scantokens{#1} % I do want to use +b as in practice I do more involved stuff here, involving recursion etc…
}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  but this fails
  \begin{mytest}
    \only<1>{ %% without the only, it works when using scantokens
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[label={45:mylabel},fill=green]{AAA};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{mytest}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\scantokens` is dangerous...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % Important, or I get issues on other code when using french babel like "! Package tikz

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytest}{+b}{%
  #1 % I do want to use +b as in practice I do more involved stuff here, involving recursion etc…
}{}

\AddToHook{env/mytest/begin}{\shorthandoff{:}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{mytest}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[label={45:mylabel},fill=green]{AAA};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{mytest}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Your environment must un-activate the French colon earlier; `tikzpicture` will not be able to do anything once the contents have been grabbed and tokenized by your environment.

By the way I am unfamiliar with xparse syntax so perhaps some important explanation is missing here.

[image: tikz]

Comment: This works also (in my brief testing) with the added `\only<1>{...}` encapsulation of OP's edit.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I was trying to do before `\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytest}{+b}{\shorthandoff{:}#1}` but I guess that `\shorthandoff{:}` arrives too late (after the parsing of the arguments)… Thanks a lot! So to recap, we need: `[fragile]` + `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` + `\AddToHook{env/mytest/begin}{\shorthandoff{:}}`. Thanks!

Comment: @tobiasBora The `#1` stands for the grabbed contents I guess, so at that point the catcode is frozen.  Except if you encapsulate it in `\scantokens`: like this ``\shorthandoff{:}\scantokens{#1}%``.  So we were on right track.  However I don't recommend too much `\scantokens` it is subtle thing.  Hence the hook way...

Comment: @tobiasBora  I am a bit confounded by the fact that apparently everything works ok without any extra once one *suppresses*  `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`... no shorthandoff, no scantokens, no addtohook... no `[fragile]` either...

Comment: unrelated but babel-french complains about OT1 encoding and the `utf8` is not needed in fact the `inputenc` is not needed nowadays I think.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification! The problem is that without `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` I get errors in other lines in my actual code.

Comment: For reference I got other troubles with the `!` char… see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684685/babel-drives-me-crazy-with-package-tikz-error-or-expected