# Babel drives me crazy with Package tikz Error: + or - expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel

I’m fighting with babel that keeps spawning `Package tikz Error: + or - expected.` when I use the calc library. In particular, some codes only work when `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` is on, while some other codes only work when `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` is off… My sanity is seriously endangered ^^’

Right now, my only hack to make this work is to disable `\shorthandoff{!}` before the `\scalebox{}`… but I find this very inelegant as it kind of defeats the purpose of babel, in particular when nodes contain `!`. Also, as I’m writting a library, it is hard to predict in advance the list of shorthands to disable automatically…

**MWE that needs \usetikzlibrary{babel} to compile**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usetikzlibrary{babel} % If you enable this, it compiles this example, but not the other one

\NewDocumentCommand{\myAnimatedNode}{}{%
  \node(afirsthidden){};%
  \node(asecondhidden){};%
  % Last node to be drawn
  \path node[at={($(afirsthidden.center)!.5!(asecondhidden.center)$)}]{A};%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myAnimatedNode
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**MWE that fail with \usetikzlibrary{babel}**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[french]{babel} % Use \begin{frame}[fragile] everywhere or you will get weird stuff with tikz

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % If you disable this, then it compiles this example, but not the other one

\begin{document}
\scalebox{.5}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(a){};
    \node(b){};
    \node[] at ($(a.north)!.5!(b.north)$){};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
%\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Combinaison of the two that will never compile**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% This document will never compile
\usetikzlibrary{babel} 

\NewDocumentCommand{\myAnimatedNode}{}{%
  \node(afirsthidden){};%
  \node(asecondhidden){};%
  % Last node to be drawn
  \path node[at={($(afirsthidden.center)!.5!(asecondhidden.center)$)}]{A};%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myAnimatedNode
\end{tikzpicture}

\scalebox{.5}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(a){};
    \node(b){};
    \node[] at ($(a.north)!.5!(b.north)$){};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Active characters are a nightmare… consider switching to lualatex to get rid of them in French. Your document compiles fine here (without loading `\usetikzlibrary{babel} `).

Comment: `\scalebox{.5}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \end{tikzpicture}
}` like any macro will not allow catcode changes, you also need `%`  to avoid adding spaces

Comment: @DanielFlipo Oh, good to know that in lualatex it compiles fine… that’s a bit weird to me but interesting ^^’

Comment: isn't there a TikZ command to scale by `0.5` factor? `\scalebox` freezes the catcodes  of its argument, so tikz babel library can not undo that.

Comment: @tobiasBora Nothing weird here: with pdflatex characters ;:!?  need to be active to provide automatic spacing before them. With lualatex (and xelatex too), there are other *much safer* ways to achieve the same thing (and more). See the `babel-french` documentation for more details.

Comment: @user691586 yeah, there is one, but it’s more complicated to use as by default only the coordinates are scaled but not the size of the text.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of making `!` safe, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% This document will never compile
\usetikzlibrary{babel} 


\NewDocumentCommand{\myAnimatedNode}{}{%
  \node(afirsthidden){};%
  \node(asecondhidden){};%
  % Last node to be drawn
  \path node[at={($(afirsthidden.center)!.5!(asecondhidden.center)$)}]{A};%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myAnimatedNode
\end{tikzpicture}


\scalebox{.5}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(a){};
    \node(b){};
    \node[] at \expanded{($(a.north)\string!.5\string!(b.north)$){}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! The issue with this solution is that the end user needs to worry about ! (i.e. the fix is applies outside of the preambule), I’d prefer a solution where people that don’t define new macros don’t need to dare about `!`… I tried to use `\string` inside \NewDocument… and disable the tikz library, but same error.

Comment: @tobiasBora write in English:-)